# About apple rejection on "location-based APIs for emergency services"

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, maps, hig

I have developed an application that tracks user Location (background Mode) with user permission for a government police service.

As Per apple Human Interface guideline:

```
4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for emergency services will be rejected
```

- So Now What **services** include  location-based APIs for **emergency services**
- Can I use Location tracking for government Service

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: 4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected. updated as 4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for emergency services will be reject : [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app rejection process **4. Location** under with section

4.3 Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected.

Ans :

> You can’t make apps to watch your employees, or make apps that rely too heavily on location. Nobody wants an accident to happen because the device was not precise enough or didn’t work correctly. Also, you can’t use the iPhone to spy on people.

need additional reference follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199241/has-apple-provide-reasoning-for-their-location-based-api-restrictions)

Comment: with out app store submission  you can do this

Comment: please see the link , the link may be hope with you

Comment: Can I use Location services to track user continuously for police services..As I heard emergency services include - Emergency Services (POLICE, AMBULANCE,FIRE) ..Please correct me regarding services if I am wrong

Comment: @Sujania -- your question is fine and valid , assume that if anybody use this is wrong way is affected to apple , if you give/submit  the proper reason to apple , if may be apple agree this , your app can come under with in distributed in a more restricted way than App Store

Comment: @Anbu.karthik can you provide a valid link as existing one not found. I also have same problem and not able to solve

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles across this.  Apple has updated their guidelines and the now relevant topic is 5.1.5:

> 5.1.5 Location Services
> Use Location services in your app only when it is directly relevant to the features and services provided by the app. Location-based APIs shouldn’t be used to provide emergency services or autonomous control over vehicles, aircraft, and other devices, except for small devices such as lightweight drones and toys, or remote control car alarm systems, etc. Ensure that you notify and obtain consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data. If your app uses location services, be sure to explain the purpose in your app; refer to the Human Interface Guidelines for best practices on doing so.

The other answer is still accurate: You cannot provide a location-based service that integrates with emergency services (police).  (unless, in the times of Covid, you work for Apple)